# Sonicwall with failover, multiple subnets, and preferred WAN interface per subnet

Tags: failover, sonicwall

I am trying to set up my Sonicwall TZ-210 as follows:

1. Two WAN interfaces (different ISPs), set up in failover mode.
2. Two LAN interfaces with different subnets
3. Each LAN subnet will have a preferred outbound WAN interface, but would failover when necessary.

In this way, each ISP is being used for a separate subnet of my network, but both subnets could failover to the other ISP if their primary went down.

I know how to do 1 and 2, but I don't know how to do 3.  I could set up a route for each subnet to go through a specific interface, but what would happen in the event of a failover?  Would it automatically update those routes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if the TZ-210 has this ability, but when using OS Enhanced like on the NSA devices, you can create a custom route and then check a box that will deactivate the route if the Interface goes down. It also has the ability to set up a logical probe so if the interface stays up, but there's a connectivity issue further upstream (like a router at the ISP goes out) it'll disable the route.

We have pretty much an identical set up: LANs on X0 and X4. WANs on X1 and X2 in failover mode. Our backup Internet line is Comcast, so I set up a custom route that makes it so my workstation uses it instead of WAN1 (so I can watch espn3.com :) ). Basically you'd be doing the exact same thing, but on a subnet level instead of a single IP address.

But once again, I'm not sure if the standard SonicWall OS has that ability. I've only seen it on the Enhanced OS.